# What is the set denoted by $\mathbb{K}$?

Tags: notation

Wikipedia's article on the [Leibniz determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) states there exists one and only function $F:M_n(\mathbb{K})\mapsto\mathbb{K}$ which is alternating, multilinear and $F(1)=1$. I assume $M_n$ is the set of $n\times n$ square matrices, build around some set or field... $\mathbb{K}$ - but what is $\mathbb{K}$?

Additionally, what is the difference between $\mapsto$ ("mapsto") and $\to$ ("to")?

Comment: $\mathbb K$ can denote a generic field

Comment: When you denote the domain and codomain of a function, you use $\to$ between them. When you denote an element in the domain, and its image in the codomain, you use $\mapsto$ between them. For instance, the function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Generally for things involving the determinant, we also require the characteristic of the field to not be 2,  because otherwise alternating is meaningless

Comment: $K$ or $\Bbb K$ refers to the German word *Körper*, which means field. In English, often denoted by $F$. However, here the map is already denoted by $F$.

Comment: @Alan I'm not well versed in fields - is this because a field characteristic two only ever has elements of 1 and 0, so the determinant goes to zero always anyway?

Comment: No, the determinant then goes to $\Bbb F_2$, so $1$ or $0$. But alternating isn't saying much if $2=0$, so $1=-1$.

Comment: [Field : Deutsch Körper](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper_(Algebra))

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you

Comment: @Alan What?! No, determinant in characteristic $2$ is fine; you just have to state the alternating property correctly: a multilinear function $V^n\to W$ is alternating if $f(v_1,\cdots, v_n)=0$ whenever there are $i\ne j$ such that $v_i=v_j$.

Comment: @IdioticShrike Also there are infinitely many fields with characteristic 2, not only $\Bbb F_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb K$ can denote a generic field ([Körper](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper_(Algebra)) in German),

though it would have been good if the Wikipedia article had defined it.

When there is a function, $\to$ indicates what domain is mapped to what codomain,

whereas $\mapsto$ indicates where it takes a particular element.

For example, $\det:M_n(\mathbb K)\to \mathbb K$, and $\det:I\mapsto1$.

Comment: $\Bbb K$ just has to be a ring, doesn't it? If I'm right, that's another defect in the article.

Comment: @TonyK:  a commutative ring, I believe